Should I erase the disk after cancelling mac os installation?
I have cancelled the mac installation due to pkdownload error 8, which I look up on google and found out that this error due to my unstable internet connection.
So I was wondering should I erase the disk and start over or can I just safely select reinstall mac os big sur from recovery mode, would this option continue from last attempt? Thanks!
Device is Macbook Air M1, 2020

Reinstall from Recovery Mode will start the installation from scratch again. AFAIK there is no way to continue an interrupted install.

Normally, the OS should download and verify itself before installing. I don't think it needs to download anything during installation. Was this a standard OS update, or some other procedure? Erasing the disk is a last resort, and not normally necessary.

@benwiggy This is complete reinstall (erase and reinstall)

By Recovery Partition, Internet Partition, or external installer disk? (Also, there's very rarely need to erase the whole disk on an M1 Mac -- just Erase all Content from System Settings.)

I erased the disk from option that comes up when I press power button for long, is that recovery partition?
